# MySQL creating table and return a specific value if row is null

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization

I am trying to create a simple Database:

Students

- First_name (May not be empty)
- Last_name (May not be empty)
- Region (IF empty, return "unknown")

I used the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
  First_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  //And my wild guess:
  Region VARCHAR(50) ISNULL(Region, "unknown")
)
```

Doesn't work :( Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop database if exists studentsdb;
create database studentsdb;
use studentsdb;

CREATE TABLE Students(
  id VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  First_name VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
  Last_name VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
  Region VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL default 'unknown',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Also, don't forget to specify a primary key!

Comment: I didn't! :D I just didn't show it here, And out of curiosity, what is ENGINE=InnoDB?

Comment: Thanks :) And the about creating the database and using it was also helpful, it's like you're reading my mind !

Answer (score 1):

use `default`

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
  First_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Region VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL default 'unknown'
)
```